# jQuery.inArray not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

So I'm using an ajax call to retrieve a user's messages. Then cross referencing them with existing messages by creating an array of their id's. I have two messages that already exists with ID of 157 and 159. Both messages are being correctly listed in the array but when I use jQuery.inArray it only seems to be able to find one of them.

```
function checkForNewMessages() {
    $CurrentMessages = [];

    $('.Message').each(function () {
        $CurrentMessages.push($(this).attr('message-id'));
    });

    console.log('Messages found');
    console.log($CurrentMessages);

    console.log('Getting Messages');
    $.ajax({url: "<?php echo $GLOBALS['SubDirectory']; ?>api/get/messenger/messagesfromfeed?feed_id=" + urlget('ID'), success: function(result){
        $Result = decodeURI_array(JSON.parse(result));
        $.each($Result, function(index) {
            if(!jQuery.inArray($Result[index]['ID'], $CurrentMessages)) {
                console.log("New Message, ID of '" + $Result[index]['ID'] + "'");
            } else {
                console.log("Old Message, ID of '" + $Result[index]['ID'] + "'");
            }
        });
    }});
}
```

console result

```
Messages found
["157", "159"]
Getting Messages
New Message, ID of '157'
Message, ID of '159'
```

URI decoded JSON

```
[{"ID":"157","CompanyID":"13","Receiver":"13","Sender":"","Message":"test line 1\r\n& test line 2\r\n\r\n","VirtualAttachments":"[{\"Type\":\"Client\",\"ID\":\"128\",\"DisplayName\":\"\"},{\"Type\":\"Quote\",\"ID\":\"20\",\"DisplayName\":\"\"}]","FileAttachments":"[{\"Name\":\"IMG_1300.JPG\",\"Location\":\"\"}]","FeedID":"23","Seen":"TRUE","CreatedOn":"1474635298"},{"ID":"159","CompanyID":"13","Receiver":"13","Sender":"15","Message":"reply test\r\n","VirtualAttachments":"[]","FileAttachments":"[]","FeedID":"23","Seen":"TRUE","CreatedOn":"1474635960"}]
```

Comment: The `$.inArray()` function does not know that you want it to look at the "ID" properties of the objects in the array. It only performs simple equality comparison.

Comment: You need to check for `-1` being returned, not coercing the result to a boolean. However a bigger problem is that `$Result[index]['ID']` is a string, not an array, so using it in `$inArray` is incorrect in the first place.

Comment: @Pointy `jQuery.inArray($Result[index]['ID'], $CurrentMessages)` is totally fine: [`jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/). `$CurrentMessages` contains the ids of the existing messages and `$Result[index]['ID']` is the id of a message from the retrieved messages.

Comment: Thanks Rory, result is index, not boolean

Comment: @Andreas ah OK, the array being searched is just the array of ID values, not the array of objects. OK then :)